# Workaround to define a new environment with beamer's ignorenonframetext option

Tags: beamer

The following code produces an error when compiling with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}

\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{myframe}[1][]{%
    \begin{frame}{#1}
        \BODY
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

This is star mode stuff.

\begin{frame}{First frame}
    Some text.
\end{frame}

\mode<presentation>{
    \begin{myframe}{title}
        Some text.
    \end{myframe}
}

\end{document}
```

Output of `pdflatex`:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{myframe} on input line 23 ended by \end{document}.
```

If i remove the `ignorenonframetext` option or use `myframe` outside the presentation mode, everything works fine.

Is there a way to make `myframe` work within the presentation mode?

Comment: Don't warp a frame in a custom environment. This will cause much more problems than it solves...

Comment: It's possible, but you usually feed a good understanding of category codes in TeX to fix the issue. So it would be easiest for you to explain your _actual_ problem here and maybe someone will just write the code to solve your exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hiding the frame environment in a custom environment is still not a good idea, however the beamer user guide shows this example which you can adapted to include your environment:

> Example: The following example shows how you can include other files in a main file. The contents of a main.tex:
>
> ```
> \documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
> \begin{document}
> This is star mode stuff.
> Let’s include files:
> \mode<all>
> \include{a}
> \include{b}
> \mode*
> ```

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}

\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{myframe}[1]{%
    \begin{frame}[environment=myframe]{#1}
        \BODY
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

This is star mode stuff.

\begin{frame}{First frame}
    Some text.
\end{frame}

\mode<all>
    \begin{myframe}{title}
        Some text.
    \end{myframe}
\mode*

\end{document}
```